# regex strawberry perl (windows) one-liner to fix multiple linefeed (0a) characters

Tags: regex, perl, strawberry-perl

In Windows, a report from MS SQL server comes to me with embedded duplicate line feeds that cause errors when reading into LOAD DATA INFILE in mySQL in a Windows environment.  I fix this using three Strawberry Perl one-liners in a Powershell script.

The Windows '\r\n' convention is recognized by Strawberry Perl and that is its output format.  I could not get Perl to recognize the empty lines with a single 0x0a linefeed, though, as the Strawberry flavor of Perl would always interpret that as a new line and include it in the output.

My solution was to simply replace all the linefeed 0x0a characters with a string unlikely to appear in the content:

```
<*  script is Powershell, initialize source file name*>
$myLoginCSV = 'User%5FProfile%5FReport.csv' 

<*  convert linefeed (0a) chars into string LINEFEEDCHAR *>
$perlarg='-i.p.bak -p -e "s/\x0A/LINEFEEDCHAR/g"'
perl $perlarg $myLoginCSV

<*  de-duplicate linefeeds*>   
$perlarg='-i.p.bak -p -e "s/(LINEFEEDCHAR){2,}/LINEFEEDCHAR/g"'
perl $perlarg $myLoginCSV

<*  restore the 0a linefeed characters by substituting for LINEFEEDCHAR *> 
$perlarg='-i.p.bak -p -e "s/LINEFEEDCHAR/\x0a/g"'
perl $perlarg $myLoginCSV
```

I tried to do this in one line, but could not figure out how. Strawberry Perl interprets linefeeds with a fixed behavior to make it compatible with Windows.  This "three liner" works well and is fast.  An attempt at this using Powershell native regex was over 10 times slower.

**Specifically in the Strawberry Perl Windows environment, is there a way to do this in fewer than three lines?**

This is not a high priority.  One lesson I took away from this is that a regex solution using Strawberry Perl in Windows can have a multi line solution but still be fast.  In the future, I won't be as wedded to a true "one-line" solution when a couple of extra lines get the job done.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with C. Tag removed.

Comment: Can't you use `\R` to match any line break sequence? To match two line breaks use `\R{2}`.

Comment: I do not want to question your approach before I know more but I would think PoSh can do this without Perl. Is Perl really required? Do you use PowerShell v2- or v3+?

Comment: @wp78de  Perl is not really required, but it's a low space/low maintenance tool that runs regex code very quickly.   Powershell can do it, but was much slower to process when I tried using PS regex. 

I did not try native PS text functions, so the comparison is not complete.  There is a chance (hope?) this code will eventually will be running in parallel in Linux, where regex and Perl are native.  (Windows for doing eyes-on data analysis, Linux for the automated daily script).   With that as a possibility, my goal is to stay with regex for text cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slurp](http://p3rl.org/run#-0[octal/hexadecimal]) and replace consecutive [newlines](http://p3rl.org/rebackslash#%5CR) with a single.

```
perl -0777 -i.p.bak -lpe "s/\R+/\n/g" User%5FProfile%5FReport.csv
```

Comment: Works as advertised, [slurp](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-0[octal/hexadecimal]) was the missing key. Much cleaner, thanks.